# Get the subject of a binding in Ruby 1.8.6

Tags: ruby

In Ruby 1.8.7 I can do the following in order to get the subject of a binding object:

```
binding.eval("self")
```

However, in Ruby 1.8.6, the eval method is private, so I expose it like this:

```
class Binding
  public :eval
end
```

Which seems to work fine, however, `binding.eval("self")` returns the binding itself, not the subject of binding.

How can I get the subject of a binding in Ruby 1.8.6? The solution doesn't need to pretty - it just needs to work until we can upgrade to 1.8.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll bet at least a nickel `eval('self', abinding)` will work:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby1.8

class Foo

  def foo
    binding
  end

end

p eval('self', Foo.new.foo)    # => #<Foo:0xb7bfe5ac>
```

This works because if you pass a binding to eval, it evaluates the string in the context of that binding.  `self` in the context of the binding is whatever `self` was when the binding was created.

Comment: Thanks Wayne. That worked! I'm not sure why though.. Also, it's 1.8.6, not 1.6.

Comment: @Joel, What can I say?  Blast my eyes!  I added an explanation.  Thanks for the check-mark!